# How do I re-open the Visual Studio Immediate Window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I accidentally closed the Immediate Window in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, and can't for the life of me figure out how/where to get it back.

Can someone please point out how I get the Immediate Window open again?

Comment: Roslyn CTP installed?

Comment: I just want the window, where while in the debugger, I can print and adjust variables...  I haven't spent much time in VS for the past year.

Comment: I believe that is the immediate window you are looking for, you can go to Debug -->Windows --> Immediate or just use <ctl><alt>I to get it back.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

To get the immediate window back you can go to `Debug --> Windows --> Immediate` or you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>  either will work to get it back.

Comment: There's no Heart emoticon on stackoverflow, I would've given you one <3

Comment: @CătălinRădoi do you mean ♡ ?

Comment: That's just cheap ASCII :)

Comment: There's always emoji, ❤️

Answer (score 21):

If  you can not see Immediate Window In Debug -> Windows menu:

1. From the menu bar, go to `View > Other Windows > Command Window`
2. Type and execute `immed` command

Answer (score 8):

In addition to what previously was mentioned by @sansa and @Mark Hall, you can also use Quick Launch:

- Press `Ctrl + Q` to focus on Quick Launch text box.
- Type `Immediate` then choose the item that appears: `Debug -> Windows -> Immediate`(<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+I</kbd>)

**Update:** For more information on Quick Launch you can check it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2013/07/17/visual-studio-2013-quick-launch/)

Comment: Ctrl-Q doesn't seem to do anything at all.  Does it have to be directed at any particular pane?

Comment: @wallyk you can find Quick Launch in the upper right corner of the IDE. For more information on Quick Launch you can see this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2013/07/17/visual-studio-2013-quick-launch/

Answer (score 1):

I was missing my immediate window and none of the above tricks worked. It turned out it was hiding on the bottom and I had to stretch it up.