# Immediate window in Visual Studio disappears at runtime

Tags: visual-studio, immediate-window

In Visual Studio 17.0 I am debugging C# code and pressed `Ctrl+Alt+i` to open an immediate window and nothing happens.  When I stop debugging and use the key combination `Ctrl+Alt+i`, the immediate window appears.  When I start debugging, the window disappears.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try restarting visual studio?

Comment: also, it may be there but the size of the window is too small to see? Try seeing if you can grab onto the stray border at the bottom of the window and dragging it to make it larger?

Comment: Yes, I restarted VS and still can't get the immediate window to open while debugging.

Comment: I checked for the window everywhere in the IDE, can't see anything hiding

Comment: did you check out some solutions posted here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815068/how-do-i-re-open-the-visual-studio-immediate-window

Comment: I had already checked out that link above before posting my own question here.  I tried launching Immediate window from Quick Launch.  No luck.  I also verified that it is not hiding anywhere within the IDE or outside