# Edit the value of a list item in Visual Studio while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022

Is this something you can't do?

You can put a breakpoint and edit an `int` variable value, but this you can't edit the value of a list item?

Comment: This questions really needs an example. (with some code for context) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the "Quick Watch" answer, you can use the [immediate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815068/how-do-i-re-open-the-visual-studio-immediate-window) to change an object that is in scope (where the breakpoint is).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `Quick watch` feature,

- Where you want to change value of list, put a debugger.
- Right click there and select Quick watch(shift + F9).
- Update the expression as below

[image]